# How do I fill multiple textboxes with data based on first text box input?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Lets say I have a database table with 3 columns: accref, company and contact and 3 matching textboxes.

I have already implemented a autosuggest feature for accref textbox which will suggest database values for the accref column. What I want is when I click on a suggested value in the accref textbox, I want the company and contact boxes to fill with the data that is in the same row as the accref.

For example,

table:

accref: HFHFHF

company: the goverment

contact: Barack Obama

When I type HFH in the accref textbox, the HFHFHF record shows up as a suggestion. Then when i click on that suggestion(it shows as a div), I want it to fill in the company text box with "The goverment" and then the contact textbox with "Barack Obama"

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>tst</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".search_keyword").keyup(function() 
{ 
    var search_keyword_value = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'search_keyword='+ search_keyword_value;
    if(search_keyword_value!='')
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            selectFirst: true,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#result").html(html).show();
                }
        });
    }
    return false;   
});

$("#result").live("click",function(e){
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.accref_name').html();   
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#search_keyword_id').val(decoded);



});

$(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search_keyword")){
        $("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});


    $("#")



});


</script>

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <input type="text" class="search_keyword" id="search_keyword_id" placeholder="Cus ref"/>
        <input type="text" class="comp_get" placeholder="Company"/>



        <div id="result"></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And search.php:

```
<?php
    include('db_connection.php');
    if(isset($_POST['search_keyword']))
    {
        $search_keyword = $dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['search_keyword']);
        $sqlQuery="SELECT db_accref, db_company FROM tbl_customers WHERE db_accref LIKE '%$search_keyword%'";
        $resAccref=$dbConnection->query($sqlQuery);

        if($resAccref === false) {
            trigger_error('Error: ' . $dbConnection->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }else{
            $rows_returned = $resAccref->num_rows;
                    }

    $bold_search_keyword = '<strong>'.$search_keyword.'</strong>';
    if($rows_returned > 0){
            while($rowAccref = $resAccref->fetch_assoc()) 
            {       
                echo '<div class="show" align="left"><span class="accref_name">'.str_ireplace($search_keyword,$bold_search_keyword,$rowAccref['db_accref']).'</span></div>';    
            }
        }else{
            echo '<div class="show" align="left"></div>';   
        }
    }   
?>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for any help and sorry if I havent made the question clear enough.

Mike

Comment: When someone selects/clicks a value, send another ajax request to get the additional information and fill in the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a listener for the click/select event so that when you click on your choice in the first dropdown, a php function gets called that will then search the database for the corresponding row of data, and return it.  Then, in the jQuery you can update the html with that returned data.

For example, you have something very similar in your code above. You have a listener on the keyup event that calls 'search.php' which returns data used to update your div #result.  This is pretty much what you need to do, but instead listen for the event that occurs when someone selects from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `tbl_customers` table contains the `accref`, `company`, and `contact`? If so, lets all fetch that and return it to the Ajax request. Lets change your `search.php` where we will fetch all the column and use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). We will store the results of each row per link `<a></a>` using `data` tags:

```
<?php

    include('db_connection.php');

    if(isset($_POST['search_keyword']))
    {

        $search_keyword = '%'.$_POST["search_keyword"].'%';

        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT db_accref, db_company, db_contact FROM tbl_customers WHERE db_accref LIKE ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $search_keyword);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($accref, $company, $contact);
        while($stmt->fetch()){

            echo '<div class="show" align="left">
                      <span class="accref_name">
                          <a href="#" data-accref="'.$accref.'"
                                      data-company="'.$company.'"
                                      data-contact="'.$contact.'"
                             class="suggestion">'.$accref.'</a>
                      </span>
                  </div>';  

        }
        $stmt->close();

    }   
?>
```

Then lets create the script, when a suggestion is clicked, it will put its data into the corresponding text fields. Lets use `.on()` as `.live()` is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) as of jQuery 1.7:

```
$(document).on("click", ".suggestion", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var elem = $(this),
        accref = elem.attr('data-accref'),
        company = elem.attr('data-company'),
        contact = elem.attr('data-contact');

    $("#accref").val(accref); /* ASSUMING THAT YOUR ACCREF TEXT FIELD HAS AN ID OF accref */
    $("#company").val(company); /* ASSUMING THAT YOUR COMPANY TEXT FIELD HAS AN ID OF company */
    $("#contact").val(contact); /* ASSUMING THAT YOUR CONTACT TEXT FIELD HAS AN ID OF contact */

    return false;

});
```